# Jquery modal - External css is not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $(function() {        
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         width : 700,
         height : 370,
         modal: true   
    });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="">
  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="310" href="www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to display popup modal when the page loads. I am getting the popup as I want. But the problem is I am getting the popup when I am using the following link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But, I don't want to use the link. So I download the files and imported into my project. When I use the downloaded CSS file I am not getting 'X' button in modal popup.
Please help me with this. Thank you.

[image: This is the one I am using the link].

[image: This is the one I am using external file]

Comment: Is the CSS in the same folder as the page? is not included inside, like a css folder?

Comment: Yes.Both are in WebContent folder.

Comment: Please help me Cheshire. What need to be change.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css downloads list of .png files which are shown below but if you use downloaded .css in your project these .png files are not getting downloaded and that's the reason 'X' is not available in dialog. You can verify through fiddler or any other network traffic capturing tool. Download all the required images and store it in your project with same folder hierarchy (themes/base/images).

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
```

As I've mentioned in my comments - you can download entire jquery theme from [here](https://jqueryui.com/download/all/).

Comment: How to get that only that image?

Comment: Get it from https://github.com - 'ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png' is here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/themes/base/images There are couple of other options: One such option (using IE) - Get it from 'Temporary Internet Files' once downloaded.

Comment: Also get it from code.jquery.com - Type 'downlaod ui-icons_222222_256x240.png from code.jquery.com' in google, it'll redirect to code.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI has it's owns images, css and javascript files.

Download your version with it's content here: http://jqueryui.com/download/

If you don't care much about the CSS, you can select de "base" option below the page. Once you download it, it will give you a zip with javascript, css and images. Try to keep the folders as they are (for example, extract the files into a folder named "jquery-ui") so images and links will work properly.

Now, you can change the style in your own CSS to achieve the style you want.